# find the Maclaurin expression

Tags: calculus, power-series

The function is 
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$
Now using the power series formulas of $e^x$ and manipulating it to become the given function it show be 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}$$ 
Now if I want to evaluate the integral of the function and give my answer in sum notation
I would get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{-x^{2n+2}}{(n+1)!}$$

Sorry I keep editing the question, there is a lot of parts to this particular question.

Comment: Certainly not. In the first place you show a single term (hence a polynomial), and assuming it is the general term of a series, this would be $-xe^x$. Please detail your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Maclaurin series of $e^x$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
one gets the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{2k}
$$